# How to run website in live server?

Tags: codeigniter, text

I have problem running my website in live server.I user cpanel.hostinger.co.uk free hosting service where i uploaded my website folder but it runs in localhost but not in live.I have checked .htaccess file to but not working.It always show 404 error. I use codeigniter 3.0 so could you please help me whats wrong??

Comment: yes i use subdomain so i will check and thank you

Comment: now it shows 500 error??

Comment: ok i think i solved it

Comment: ok it runs all thanks to you.